# Why do i get an error while using the bookmark API for making chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
        'parentId': bookmarkBar.id,
        'title': 'Extension bookmarks'
    },
        function(newFolder) {
        console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
      });

});
```

I use the above code to add bookmark folder in the Bookmark Bar but when I run the code, I get an error "Error in event handler: ReferenceError: bookmarkBar is not defined". Why does this happen? How do I tackle this error?

Comment: Your code doesn't define bookmarkBar anywhere.

Comment: How do i get the id of the bookmark bar? I am sorry .. but there are just no tutorials of the bookmark API Chrome extension on the internet. if you know a site, please mention

Comment: The code you have posted uses a variable named `bookmarkBar` but it doesn't define this variable anywhere.